# Re-run python code from command line (with an additional flag) in case of MemoryError

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, cmd, out-of-memory

I have a python code that runs from the command line (Windows) and crashes on a MemoryError.
While I work on solving the error I want the code to re-run, with a flag, for example python c:\python_code.py --rerun, until I get a successful exit code.

Is this possible in Windows?
Also, it is key that the code restart, otherwise it is my understanding that the memory is not cleared.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason not to wrap this in a separate function?
Something like this-
    import subprocess
    status = subprocess.call("python", "c:\my_code.py arg0 arg1 arg2")
    while status != 0:
        status = subprocess.call("python", "c:\my_code.py arg0 arg1 arg2 flag")

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your code around:

```
if flag==rerun:
    while True:
        try:
            os.system('python python_code.py')
            break
        except MemoryError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I did, with a small change - when the MemoeryError exception was raised I exited the code with code 12 (the error number for ENOMEM (http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) and while the code returns 12 I keep rerunning it with an optional flag --rerun